# Не работает sudo

Tags: linux-mint, sudo

`/etc/sudoers` принадлежит пользователю с `uid 1000`, а должен принадлежать пользователю с `uid 0`

Linux Mint 17.2 Kernel 3.13

Comment: вопрос не очень понятен, вы не знаете как сменить принадлежность файла пользователю ?

Comment: что бы сменить права - нужен root

Comment: Поподробней опишите ситуацию (что за линукс, виртуалка или нет и т.п.)

Comment: В любом случае почитайте [как reset root password](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Reset_root_password_%28%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%29) (можете нагуглть кучу подобных справок)

Comment: Господа **закрывающие вопрос**! Подумайте, а где еще человеку задать **очевидно практический и важный для него вопрос**?

Comment: @avp: очень хотелось бы, чтобы именно здесь он мог задать такой вопрос и получить ответ. Закрывают, кстати, не за оффтопик, а потому что подробностей недостаточно.

Comment: нужен русский вариант superuser

Comment: @zenden2k: Stack Exchange по крайней мере в ближайшее время не планирует открывать не-англоязычных сайтов кроме клонов StackOverflow. Так что русский вариант SU — это либо Ru.SO, либо вообще не будет.

Comment: я бы не задавал сюда вопрос если бы нашел его решение в гугле,  я всегда так делаю. Все те ответы в гугле я проверял и с помощью них я не смог решить проблему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. во время загрузки вам надо попасть в загрузочное меню:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   для этого надо периодически нажимать что-нибудь типа <kbd>shift</kbd> или стрелки вверх (вниз) или <kbd>escape</kbd> или ещё что-нибудь.
2. остановившись на первом пункте, нажмите <kbd>tab</kbd> (как и написано в подсказке) для редактирования загрузочных опций. там допишите (через пробел) слово `recovery` и нажмите <kbd>enter</kbd> для загрузки:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. загрузка остановится на *recovery menu*, в котором вам надо стрелками вверх-вниз выбрать пункт, озаглавленный *root (drop to root shell prompt)*, и нажать <kbd>enter</kbd>:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. вы получите *root*-овый *shell*, в котором сможете проделать все необходимые административные действия:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Теперь смените пользователя программой `chown`. см. подробности в `man chown`

Comment: я в такое заходил и знаю как, мне бы что дальше делать. Но все таки благодарен за Ваш труд оформление поста, но я это знал

Comment: в каком смысле «что»? вы же сами написали в вопросе — файл принадлежит не тому пользователю. смените пользователя программой `chown`. см. подробности в `man chown`